# Why and how did South Park use music from Eureka seveN?

Tags: music, eureka-seven

I noticed this some 12 or so years ago when the episode first aired, but South Park uses a snippet of "Uncontrolled Self" from Eureka seveN during the train chase scene with Britney Spears, and then immediately pivots to another song once they enter the closet. I could only find a snippet in Español, and the music is barely audible in this dub (it's very loud in the English dub). Here's the clip:

https://youtu.be/EAzmw6umxUQ?list=PLpabzom3lBLGjJNU8CRxlrV7IbBnRPoYT&t=142

And here's the moment in Uncontrolled Self that they pulled from:

https://youtu.be/4lLAPgZN4tI?t=25

Using ViewSync, this becomes completely apparent:

https://viewsync.net/watch?v=EAzmw6umxUQ&t=142&v=4lLAPgZN4tI&t=25&mode=solo

Do both South Park and Eureka seveN pull inspiration from the same classical music? Is this song copyleft audio freely available? Or did South Park Studios just rip it to put it in the episode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the big features of Eureka Seven is its use of music and in particular, remixes. The writer of the story is really into music and even named several of the Gekkostate mechs after some audio equipment.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_Seven#Development

From what I can tell, the clip from Eureka Seven you provided might be a remix of a track called "Fletcher" by Johan Van Barel.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_pFpktmpDU

About halfway through and towards the end, it has some very recognisable dramatic sting effects that I am sure have been used in various tv shows and movies over many years.

If it is indeed inspired by this, then it's quite possible that the production for South Park used it as a dramatic audio sting much in the same way the "Wilhelm scream" is used in many action movies.

Comment: Wow!!! That's spot-on. Great find. I think you're right that they remixed audio from the same sources. Thanks so much for creating an account to post your answer, where there's no such thing as a necropost on Stack Exchange!

Comment: I have recently been rewatching Mythbusters and guess what sound effect makes an appearance on occasion....

Comment: Also, it's something that's been bugging me for a while too. I've heard this sound effect in a number of places and wondered about it's origins.

I also have a suspicion that "Fletcher" might not be the true origin....

Answer (score 2):

Most likely in the same way companies like Crunchyroll buy licenses to stream anime. TV shows, etc. can buy licenses to use music made by other people.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_licensing

Comment: South Park does really went that far for single OST? :/